# Multiple prefix matches for routing to same cluster in envoy

Tags: envoyproxy

For envoy routing, I've multiple prefix matches for routing to different clusters. For routing to same cluster, I have to repeat the match section. For e.g., this is a section of routes in enovy-config.yaml

```
          - match:
              prefix: "/api/v1/config/"
            route:
              cluster: cluster2
          - match:
              prefix: "/api/service/risk/"
            route:
              cluster: cluster2
```

I cannot match on `/api` as most of my services start with that and I am ending up writing multiple match/prefix for routing to same cluster. Is there a way to group the prefixes that go to same cluster without having to repeat the `match` section? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, no.  If you want to do explicit prefix matching, then you need these repeat structures for each one.

However, if you can instead do matching based off of a regex pattern, then you can use the `safe_regex` matching to route a bunch of paths to a given cluster.  [api docs here](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/route/v3/route_components.proto#config-route-v3-routematch)

Comment: Yes. Found from the documentation that nesting or grouping is not possible and used the regex. But yaml looked ugly and ended up doing the multiple match prefixes.